# How do I Export Apple mail database to Outlook 2016 for Mac?

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office, file-conversion

I don't like the series Mail/iCal from Apple, reason why I bought Outlook 2016 for Mac. I was able to transfer the contacts but I am facing difficulties transferring the email database. It seems that outlook doesn't support the email format of the apple mail.

Is there a way to transfer all the emails with their categories from Apple Mail to Outlook 2016 for Mac ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to add info such as: (1) What version of macOS and Apple Mail are you running? (2) Can you clarify what you've tried? There's no point people here suggesting things you've already done. (3) By _categories_ what do you actually mean? Mailboxes? Rules? Colour-coding? Something else?

Comment: Are all your mails on a IMAP server? or on "On My Mac"

Comment: Do you even need to export? Most times you can configure outlook to point directly at your mail service that has the mails and it will cache locally the mail just as Apple’s app does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Mail archives its database in .mbox format and outlook for mac can only import either .pst or .olm format files. It definitely cannot import emails exported from apple mail. If you have an Imap enabled account then you can directly sign in to the outlook mac, it might take a while depending on your email database size, your files will start uploading.

You can take alternatives as well, where some application are available that can convert the file format. Here is one I found online: http://mailexporterpro.com/

I hope this suits your needs.

Comment: Mail exporter pro made the export and import easy and quick. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found some similar threads about this query, might be helpful, have a look:-

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac/ms-outlook-2011-email-import/a8de536d-a893-49d9-a9b6-c58ddf045ee4
- https://macosx.com/threads/import-mails-form-apple-mail-to-outlook-2011-for-mac.322130/#post1526985
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5064394

Answer (score 0):

To export your mail database from Apple mail to Outlook 2016 you would be requiring a converter to perform such action. **Mail Extractor Pro** would be suggested to you as it converts your entire mail database from Apple Mail, Mbox, Postbox, Gmail, Thunderbird to PST file format for your Outlook for both Mac and windows.

For more details: **http://www.mailextractorpro.com**